# validation function error, 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a validation function, `submitForm` function is to check other function return value true or false, but I have this error, I don't know why.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
var ClassSignUpValidation = function (){};

ClassSignUpValidation.prototype.CheckName = function (_target)
{
    return false;
}

ClassSignUpValidation.prototype.CheckPassword = function (_target)
{
    return false;
}

//SUBMIT FORM VALIDATION
ClassSignUpValidation.prototype.SubmitForm = function (event)
{
  var sumbit_errorspan = $("#submit-errorResult");
  //array validation function
       var validators = [this.CheckName, this.CheckPassword];
       // bypass all function
       var valid = validators.reduce(function(valid, validator){
       return validator() && valid;
       }, true);

       if(valid){
       sumbit_errorspan.html('');
       }else{
       sumbit_errorspan.css('color', 'red');
       sumbit_errorspan.html('sumbit not requirements.');
       }
       return valid;
}
```

error point

```
   ClassSignUpValidation.prototype.CheckName = function (_target)
    {
      //set target id to jquery
      _target = "#" + _target;

      //set variable
      var username_target = $(_target);
      var username_value = username_target.val();
      var username_errorspan = $("#user-errorResult");

    ****//here is the error****
    if (username_value.length >= 4){
       $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/main/class/classvalidation.php",
        async:false,
        data:{
        "username": username_value
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
          var usernameAvailable = JSON.parse(data);
          var color = usernameAvailable.exists ? "#dfe0e6" : "red";
          username_errorspan.html(usernameAvailable.message);
          username_errorspan.css("color", color);
          username_target.css("border-color", color);
          if(usernameAvailable.exists === true){
            return true;
          }
        }
      });
    };

    return false;
    }
```

error here is the error point in

```
    if (username_value.length >= 4){
```

Comment: The error doesn't correspond to the code you provide. I see no length property access anywhere. Check if other part of your code is culprit.

Comment: i am not sure what's wrong

Comment: your CheckName function expects a _target or else it will be null. So whole process falls apart and length of null will be undefined. `return validator() && valid;` is the line where you can pass the _target

Comment: i dont get it fully , can you give me example how to pass the variable in? thanks you.

Comment: suppose your name field have an id "namefield", then return validator("namefield") && valid; will work for CheckName. But you will need to figure-out another efficient approach for other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your IF statement should look like this:

```
username_value && username_value.length >= 4
```

That way you'll be sure that **there is a value** (and so an element as well) and that it's length is greater than 4.